# HTML body to have the same size as its contents

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an img element inside a body, how do I make the body to have the same width and height of its content?

Currently its expanding to the complete viewport of the browser.

[image]

Html:

```
<html> 
     <head></head> 
     <body style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; margin-top: 0%; margin-bottom: 0%"> 
         <img width="200" height="200" src="http://someimage.jpg"/> 
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your body would only be 200px wide then what would be on the right side of the body? Vacuum? :-). Can you explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: `body` is a block like element so you would need to change it to `inline-block`. But honstety I don't know if styling `body` this wat is well supported cross browser. Why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: @StijnGeukens the `html` element ;)

Comment: The body element's height is technically already as small as its content (add a different background color to the body and html elements to see it:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/fbdkz7li).  Is there a practical application to this question?  Are you trying to do this for centering purposes?